# NSPredicate to use IN and LIKE at the same time

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have an array of search values that I would like to use in conjunction with a LIKE query in an NSPredicate:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"textField IN LIKE[c] %@", array];
```

This doesn't work, but is this possible to see if *textfield* has any LIKE comparisons to each value in the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `NSCompoundPredicate`. It let's you combine a series of **LIKE** predicates with **OR**.

```
NSMutableArray *subpredicates = [NSMutableArray array];
for(NSString *text in array)
 [subpredicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"textfield LIKE %@",text]];
NSPredicate *finished = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:subpreds];//Your final predicate
```

Comment: Is it possible to do something like: WHERE x = 0 AND y = 0 AND (field IN array OR anotherField LIKE[c] array

Comment: There are **orCompoundPredicateWithSubpredicates** and **andCompoundPredicateWithSubpredicates** that make **OR** or **AND** predicates respectivley.You can combine them the way you want